# Mongoose group by lookup field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I'm new at NodeJS and Mongoose and I'm trying to do some advanced queries.

I have three documents (Category, Subcategory and Product)

**Category.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category');
```

**Subcategory.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var SubcategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: Buffer, contentType: String },
    idcategory: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }
});

mongoose.model('Subcategory', SubcategorySchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Subcategory');
```

**Product.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    idsubcategory: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subcategory', required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true }
});

mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product');
```

So, a Product has a Subcategory which has a Category.
Since I have this structure I wanna count my products by categories. i.g.

```
[
  { "categoryName": "cat1": quantity: 10 },
  { "categoryName": "cat2": quantity: 5 },
  { "categoryName": "cat3": quantity: 2 }
]
```

I already tried a *$lookup* with *$group* without success since I dont understand the aggregate at all.

**Mongoose: "4.11.6"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CategoryModel.aggregate([
    // stage 1: join subcategories
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'subcategories',      // collection to join
            localField: '_id',          // field from categories collection
            foreignField: 'idcategory', // field from subcategories collection
            as: 'subcategory'           
        }
    },
    // at this point, each document will have an additional subcategory array with all the "joined" documents from subcategories collection
    // stage 2: we need to "unwind" the subcategory array in order to join the products
    // when you unwind an array, it's like making each element in the array have its own document
    {
        $unwind: '$subcategory'
    },
    // stage 3: join products
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'products',               // collection to join
            localField: 'subcategory._id',  // field from our updated collection
            foreignField: 'idsubcategory',  // field from products collection
            as: 'products'
        }
    },

    // EDIT

    // stage 4: strip out all fields except _id, category name, and quantity (number of products)
    {
        $project: {
            name: true, 
            quantity: { $size: '$products' }
        }
    },
    // stage 5: group by category ID
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',                        // group by category ID
            categoryName: { $first: '$name' },  // get category name
            quantity: { $sum: '$quantity' },    // sum the quantities
        }
    }
]).exec(...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikey. But there is a little issue in this code. The problem is the _$first_. This _$first_ is showing the fisrt group with the **category.id**. But when I have two **subcategories** for the same category, it doesn't works. I tried to use _$sum_ instead but it doesn't works as well.

Comment: @brunnogrillo Maybe try flipping stage 4 and 5. Basically, after stage 3, we'll have all the necessary info we need. Then in stage 4, take out relevant fields including getting the quantity for each category+subcategory document. Then stage 5, group by category where we sum the quantities.

Comment: Actually, after your edit, it works. Thanks @mickey it was very helpful